# Referencing for Air Quality Monitoring

Tags: sensors, environmental-engineering, chemistry, calibration

I asked the same question in electronics sub, but since it is more general I am asking it here again. I bought the Sharp dust sensor GP2Y1010AU0F. Below are the graph of readings indoor for ~5 minutes, it seemed quite smooth to me. The peak at the 10th second is done on purpose for showing the max reading. The ug/m3 values are created using the reference graph in the data-sheet.

[image]

I want to compare my readings to some references, there are some papers giving the measurements for smoke, candle, deodorant etc. However, it would be better to create and environment with known PM information.I don't have any reliable machinery for creating or measuring the environment PM density. So far, I though of creating a chemical reaction in a 10-20m3 closed room and periodically increasing the reaction parameters. I need your suggestions for testing the sensor with a known input.

Comment: Why a 10-20m3 closed room ? how much smoke etc do you need to add? Why not a small pipe loop ie closed loop : that would have a small volume of air to control...

Comment: Because doing it in a room would be a more generalized version requiring less things. Also this sensor is to be used indoor/outdoor, hence having a larger environment would show me the process of things happening in a wider time-line. Still, I can do it in a small area as you suggested for starters.